# Como obter um recurso que está no mesmo pacote da classe que irá usá-lo?

Tags: java

Eu criei um projeto Java com a seguinte estrutura:

```
src
 |-br.foo.settings
 |     |- settings.json
 |     |- Settings.java
 |   
 |- ... outros pacotes ...
```

Como estou acostumado com o formato de arquivos JSON, pensei em criar um para definir as principais configurações da aplicação (como podem ver, ele está no pacote `br.foo.settings`).

Para ilustrar, nele há algumas informações sobre repositório, dependências, diretórios onde devo salvar dados da aplicação, etc. Um exemplo de estrutura:

```
{
    locais: [
        {"padrao":"stackoverflow"},
        {"usuario":"2"},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

A classe `Settings` é responsável por obter um valor de configuração com base na *key*. Por exemplo, suponha que eu queira o valor da *key* "padrão" (em "locais") eu chamaria um
método que retorna o "stackoverflow".

#### O problema...

Tudo isso funciona normalmente quando faço testes e executo o projeto no IDE, mas quando dou *build* e tento executar o .jar criado é lançada uma exceção de `NullPointerException` por não encontrar o arquivo `settings.json`.

#### Eis minha primeira dúvida:

Esse arquivo não é empacotado junto com o .jar?

---

Bom, continuando, como o arquivo está na mesmo pacote da classe `Settings`, estou usando o seguinte código pra obter o arquivo:

```
// Settings.java 
File arquivoDeConfiguracao = FileUtils.toFile(getClass().getResource("settings.json"));
```

O uso de "`getClass().getResource(...)`" sempre funcionou comigo, mas nesse caso está me frustrando!

Existe algum modo de empacotar esse arquivo .json junto com o .jar? Tenho quase certeza que o problema é esse, pois o método que estou usando para obter o arquivo está pegando um objeto nulo, mas o engraçado é que quando executo pelo IDE funciona OK.

#### Minha segunda dúvida é:

Estou usando o Maven e notei que ele possui um diretório chamado "resources". Se eu mover esse arquivo JSON para lá, ele será empacotado junto com o .jar?

<sub>Aceito sugestões de alternativas, por enquanto to considerando essa de ler o arquivo JSON a melhor. Por exemplo, alguma outra forma de escrever um arquivo com dados que devem ser usados pela aplicação que não seja criando `enum`?</sub>

Comment: Para responder sua primeira pergunta você pode abrir o `.jar` com alguma aplicação que abre arquivos zip e ver se o arquivo está lá dentro. Se ele estiver lá dentro, provavelmente o problema está no parâmetro do `getResource()` que teria que ser o caminho do arquivo baseado na raiz do jar.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro vou checar, não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: A sua segunda pergunta é mais fácil, "Sim!". Se você está usando maven é sempre aconselhável usar a estrutura de diretório deles, visto que o maven foi desenvolvido sob o conceito "Convenção sobre configuração". O diretório `res` vai empacotado junto do jar a menos que você especifique que não quer empacotá-los.

Comment: @GabrielOshiro Eu extrai os arquivos do .jar e o arquivo JSON está lá, seguindo a mesma estrutura que disse na pergunta. Não sei qual é o problema, estou quase iniciando o projeto do zero por não conseguir resolver isso há semanas.

Comment: Qual o caminho que você passa para `getResource()`? Tenta passar o caminho do seu jar trocando os pontos dos packages por barras `src/br/foo/settings/settings.json`

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas @GabrielOshiro, consegui resolver! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problemas, mas fiz algumas alterações na estrutura do projeto.

```
src
 |- java
 |    |
 |    |- br.foo.settings
 |           |- Settings.java
 |- resources
       |- settings.json
```

Estou conseguindo obter o arquivo por meio de `InputStream` da seguinte forma:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputstr = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("settings.json"); // YEAAH!
inputstr.close();
```

<sub>Caso a forma acima não funcione, algumas pesquisas no Google me levaram à [essa biblioteca](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java/?v=source) que faz uma busca mais precisa pelo arquivo.</sub>

Para converter esse *stream* para uma String, segui [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/4056678) (sensacional) no StackOverflow fazendo uso de um objeto `Scanner`.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream inputstr = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("settings.json");

        String json = new Scanner(inputstr, "UTF8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println(json); // YEAHH :D
        inputstr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita para que conste nas estatísticas que o problema foi resolvido (importante para a fase Beta do SOpt) ;-)

Comment: @GabrielOshiro O sistema impõe que você só pode aceitar a sua própria resposta pelo menos 2 dias depois da pergunta ter sido postada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tô ligado, bro ;)